# How to create assembly out of webservice in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services, compilation, getjson

I have a web-service which contains the confidential information (login details), so i need to compile it into assembly. Here i have 2 questions for this process.

1. How do i compile web-service into an assembly.
2. How do i call the web-service in Jquery as i was using below getJSON code to call web-service
   $.getJSON("http://[external domain]/[servicename].asmx", function () {...})
    So once i compile the web-service shall i be using the same syntax for calling web-service.

Can anyone please let me know how to do above things.

Comment: You need to do what now ???

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: How would compiling it make it more secure?